# Returning more cells in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using `MGTwitterEngine` and have almost EVERYTHING figured out, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to return more tweets in my timeline! It receives around 20 tweets by the method I am using and if I add a integer for example: `return count = 100;`, I can tell I now have 100 cells when it loads and by the scroll indicator but when I scroll to that 18- 19 cell I get this error:

> SIGABRT
>   -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 20 beyond bounds [0 .. 19]'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

I know what it means: theres no more information to receive at cell 20.  I'm baffled and went in and out of `MGTwitterEngine` looking for a default tweet count but I can't find it. I am using the dump to create my `NSString`s and the dump only seems to give around 20 tweets per login. Please help, any suggestions are good in my book! Thank you!

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int count = [tweets count];
    // Return just enough cells to fill the screen during loading ....
    if (count == 0)
        count = MyCustomRowCount;
        else {
            //Here is where I think I need to add a else return integer but dont know how
        }
    return count;
    return [tweets count];
    return [authors count];
    return [avatarsURL count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) { 
        [cell autorelease];
    }

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];
    /*
     //Here it adds a nice shadow to the table view but will crash on rotation and send a  
     wird dump  !!!???? 
     tableView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
     tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
     tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
     tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;     
     */
    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[(Tweet*)[authors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] author]];  
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] tweet]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:10];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[(Tweet*)[retweetCount objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
    reTweetCount]];
    [cell.textLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.contentView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    // cell.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Cell :%i", indexPath.row];    


    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image with 
    SDWebImageManager
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[(Tweet*)[avatarsURL   
                                                                   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]avatarURL]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"]];

    //add gradient to cell 
    UIImage *gradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientcell2.png"];
    UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:gradient];
    cellimage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell.backgroundView = cellimage;
    [cellimage release];      

    UIImage *selectedGradient = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedcell.png"];
    UIImageView *selectedCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectedGradient];
    selectedCell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedCell;    
    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];     
    return cell;
}

//get cell accessory  
-(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row < [tweets count]){

    }    
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

// custom hieght 
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return 80;
}

//select tweet bring to detail view ..... Also bring in the Users information who made the tweet!
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    //Get the selected tweets
    NSString *selectedTweet = [(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] tweet]; 
    NSString *selectedUser = [(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] author];
    NSString *selectedUserInfo = [(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] user];
    NSString *retweetCount = [(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] reTweetCount ];
    // NSString *selectedUserFriendsCount = [(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userFriendsCount];------HUH? NO soup for ME!
    NSString *selectedUserFollowersCount = [(Tweet*)[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userFollowersCount];   

    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
    TwitterDetailViewController*dvController = [[TwitterDetailViewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:@"TwitterDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedTweet = selectedTweet;
    dvController.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    dvController.selectedUserInfo = selectedUserInfo;
    // dvController.selectedUserFriendsCount = selectedUserFriendsCount;------Doesnt reconize the call for some odd reason!
    dvController.selectedUserFollowersCount = selectedUserFollowersCount;   
    dvController.retweetCount = retweetCount;
    dvController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:webController animated:YES];-------would rather use  navagation controller for several obvious reasons
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

Comment: I suggest improving the code formatting and adding the `iphone` or `ios` tags.

Comment: why are you doing:

  if (cell == nil) { 
        [cell autorelease];
  }


    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    [cell autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

UITableView doesn't it like it when you gave it something inconsistant. If you change the model, you need to call [tableView reloadData] or if you want to animate the changes call [tableView beingUpdate][tableView endUpdate] with all the insert/remove cell operations in the middle.

On another note, I'm not sure why you doing here:

```
NSString *identifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) { 
        [cell autorelease];
}

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[cell autorelease];
```

First if `(cell == nil)`, calling auto release on it won't do anything.

The reuse identifier thing is a flyweight pattern. If `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns nil, it means it doesn't have a cell object in the pool for you to use and you should alloc a new one for it. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` also already returns an autorelease object.

Instead try this:

```
NSString *identifier = @"mytweetcell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) { 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zac! I appreciate it! I used the code you provided which doesn't change the functionality of anything but definitely seems cleaner. I still have the issue of trying to retrieve more tweets then just 20. Only thing I can think of it has a default tweet count of 20 somewhere in the MGTwitter Engin and I caint find it. I know in the older versions is had a #define DEFAULT_TWEET_COUNT = 20 but now it is gone and I can not seem to find it anywhere.... So is it possible to tell my table view to reload the data when scrolling? If so how would one attempt that ?